# 'beforeEach' should only be used in 'describe' function

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm writing a test, but it gives me an error: "Error: 'beforeEach' should only be used in 'describe' function"

Heres the test:

```
describe('SomeComponent', () => {
  let value;

  beforeEach(() => {
    value = 1;
  });

  it('should be 1', () => {
    expect(value).toBe(1);
  });
});
```

[image]

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?